# React native real device can not see object but emulator can

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this `Text`

```
<Text style={styles.accountText}>
              {GetAccount.name === undefined ? 'Account 1' : GetAccount.name}
            </Text>
```

GetAccount contains following:

```
 { "active": undefined,
   "name": "1"
 }
```

The problem is,`GetAccount.name === undefined ? 'Account 1' : GetAccount.name` is working on emulator, but when it is giving me error : `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'GetAccount.name')` on real device.

Any suggestions why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: from where you get GetAccount

Comment: from redux-store and it s coming correctly, also this error only appear on real device and on emulator it is working fine

Comment: @user14587589 kindly share more code that are related to GetAccount

Comment: What does `GetAccount` do?

Comment: As the name follows,it contains information of the account such as `name`,I'm trying to pass this name in the `Text` but it is giving me undefined error and i dont know,because it is clearly working on the emulator

Comment: Run your code on real device and try to console `GetAccount`, then let us know what you get

Comment: it is giving me `undefined` on real device,and on emulator `'name':'2'`